# Size difference between powershell and command line generated txt files

Tags: command-line, powershell, textfiles

I encountered a situation I'm unable to explain and understand. I created a text file by running the following command in command line: `certutil -v -template > documents\templates.txt`

Because I needed to do it on six servers and differentiate the files by name I decided to use powershell and use the $env:COMPUTERNAME variable instead so that I don't have to modify the command on each server. So I opened PS ISE and typed: `certutil -v -template | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\$env:COMPUTERNAME-templates.txt`

I noticed the file generated by powershell was exactly twice the size. When I tried to run fc command in command line to compare the files the result was that the files are too different. When I put content of these files to Excel (one file to column A, second to column K) and scanned for differences just by using my eyes while scrolling down, I didn't notice any differences and both files have the same number of rows. When I created an empty text file on my laptop and copied the content of the powershell file in it, after saving it has the same size as the command line file.

I mean, the size difference is 200 kB, so not an issue, but powershell created a file double the size of the command line. What's the reason for that? Why is txt file generated by Powershell twice as large as when generated by command line? In case of bigger files it might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe powershell makes a UTF-16 based file versus a UTF-8 file.

Therefore in powershell each character is actually 2 bytes.

I did a **save as** in notepad, and save it as a UTF-8, and the file size is 1/2.

Comment: Just beat me to it.  You can also open the files in Notepad++ and view the encoding there.  CMD generates a file in UTF-16 LE BOM, CMD generates UTF-8.

Comment: Or just TYPE {filename} from the command line. A UTF16 file will have IIRC two bytes at the beginning of the file that UTF-8/ANSI files don't. It shows up as a graphic character when you TYPE the file.

Comment: You can also open a `.txt` file in **Notepad** and then access the `Save as ...` dialog -- the `Encoding:` selector will be displaying the file's current encoding.